# Convert code in async await format. Also change the output structure in described manner

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, postgresql, api

```
const getExercises = (plan: any) => {
  var promises: any[] = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let day in plan) {
      var exercises = plan[day];
      for (let muscle in exercises) {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var query = format("select * from %I where id in (%L)", muscle, exercises[muscle]);
          pool
            .query(query)
            .then((result: any) => {
              if (result) {
                resolve(result.rows);
              } else {
                reject({ error: `No ${plan} plan exists` });
              }
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
              console.log(err);
              reject({ error: `No ${plan} plan exists` });
            });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
      }
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((finalPlan) => {
      resolve(finalPlan);
    });
  });
};

router.get("/workout-plan/:plan", (req: any, res: any) => {
  const planName = req.params.plan.toLowerCase();
  getExercises(getPlan(planName))
    .then((finalPlan) => {
        res.json(finalPlan);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.json(error);
    });
});
```

```
const PPL: plan = {
  d1: {
    chest: [1, 2, 3],
    triceps: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  d2: {
    back: [1, 2, 3],
    biceps: [1, 2, 3],
  },
};

export const plans: { [name: string]: plan } = {
  ppl: PPL,
};
```

I need to convert above in async await to simplify. Also, my current output has structure like [[{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}]]. But I need as {d1: [], d2: []}.
I can't pass object in promise.all. The code is being too complicated.

Comment: why don't you try to use async functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Talk is cheap

```js
async function getExercise(table: string, id: number) {
  const query = format("select * from %I where id in (%L)", table, id)
  try {
    const result = await pool.query(query)
    return result.rows
  } catch(err) {
    return null
  }
}

async function getExercises (plan: any) {

  return Promise.all(plan.map((exercises, day) => async () => Promise.all(exercises.map((exercise, id) => async () => getExercise(id, exercise)).then(results => {
       return {
         [day]: results
       }
     })))
  ).then(results => {
    return results.reduce((a,c) => ({
      return {...a, ...c}
    }) ,{})
  })
}
```

---

You have to move the `resolve` right after all queries are `finished`. But in the code, you just put the `resolve` after the loop. When `resolve` gets executed, the promises(I guess the queries are promises as well, or something async) of querying data may not be resolved.

To wait until all promises of querying data are resolved, you can make use of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Like:

```
let promises = []
//put the loop here and add each of the promise to the `promises` array
Promise.all(promises).then((finalPlan) => {
  resolve(finalPlan)
})
```

Comment: I've modified the code. But I've some more doubts . Can you help me with the same? I've updated the question.

Comment: @JayM Added async-wait version to simplify the process. It's just the code of my thinking, feel free to change to your version.